# Null element in ArrayList causing 'Cannot bind argument to parameter' error

Tags: powershell, arraylist, parameters, null, powershell-2.0

### Problem

When calling function `f $array` in code below (PowerShell v2), I am getting an error:

> f : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'csvObject1' because it is null.

### My Code

```
$hash1 = @{
    dependent_name = 'ADDM-Fun-3';
}
$obj1  = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $hash1
$array = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@( $obj1, $null )

function f () {
    Param(
        [parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
        [System.Collections.ArrayList]$array
    )
    "Hello"
}

f $array
```

### Question

Why does Powershell do this?  It seams to me to be a design flaw - but maybe I am not seeing the big picture.

### Comments

I believe this error is occurring because of the second line in the `ArrayList` is `$null`.  I am slightly shocked by this 'finding' because:

1. It has taken my about 4 hours to track down the issue.
2. This seams to imply that using strong type defintions in the function is a bad idea because it causes PowerShell to check every element in the array which is an unexepected overhead.
3. If I remove `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` from the function definition, the problem goes away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `AllowNullAttribute` as stated in [about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters help topic](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
Param
(
    [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
    [AllowNull()]
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$array
)
```

It is some kind of defensive programming. PS automatically unwraps arrays and hastables when pipelined. Think globally - you don't want empty server name in list of other server names when you pass bunch of them to function.

Comment: Thanks.  Both answers above are great.  Coming from a Java and .NET background, it has taken me a while to get used to this "Automatic Unwrapping".  I really don't like using the magic comma on return values.  I have started passing parameters into functions and return values out out of functions using Properties on a PSObject.  It is slightly more overhead - but at least I get predictable results.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why PowerShell generates an exception as null is a valid member for ArrayList. However, you can force your parameter validation by allowing nulls.

Like this:

```
[parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)][AllowNull()][System.Collections.ArrayList] $array
```

Then there is no exception generated.